# Can't get disqus comments appear in custom template

Tags: php, wordpress

I made a template for sub-pages of a page in wordpress. The problem is that disqus comments are appearing only under 1st sub page. For example  is working fine but the rest of the pages show default wordpress comments. If i change the 1st page id to let's say  then it works on that particular page but not the rest. I think it has something to with the way i have entered php code.

```
                                <?php
            /**
             * @package WordPress
             * @subpackage DID
             */
            /*
            Template Name: Season 4 - Contestant
            */
            get_header(); ?>
                    <div id="leftColumn" style="width:98%;"><?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="grid">

            <?php if (is_page(5503)) { ?>
                <ul class="contestant-performance">
                    <?php if($results = lpcf_raw_output( array('field' => 'performer_id', 'having' => 'performer_id,401', 'orderby' => 'cfvalue:episode', 'order' => 'ASC'))) { foreach($results as $post) { ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo $post->permalink ?>" title="<?php echo $post->post_title ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_field('image_facebook'); ?>" /></a>
                            <h2><?php echo $post->title ?></h2>
                            </li>
                    <?php } } ?>
                </ul>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if (is_page(5514)) { ?>
                <ul class="contestant-performance">
                    <?php if($results = lpcf_raw_output( array('field' => 'performer_id', 'having' => 'performer_id,402', 'orderby' => 'cfvalue:episode', 'order' => 'ASC'))) { foreach($results as $post) { ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo $post->permalink ?>" title="<?php echo $post->post_title ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_field('image_facebook'); ?>" /></a>
                            <h2><?php echo $post->title ?></h2>
                            </li>
                    <?php } } ?>
                </ul>
            <?php } ?>

            </div>

            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
            <?php comments_template(); ?>
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
            </div>
            <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Can you please remove the parts you verified are not causing the glitch? It's awfully hard to read that code listing. And I figure your disqus related code is in `comments_template()`?

Comment: Sorry about that, Edited.

Comment: Your php seems to be alright, are you sure the disqus plugin is able to handle rendering multiple comment sections?

Comment: I even tried putting the code in separate template files. The disqus plugin javascript is not appearing in the rest of the sub pages, only the first one and that too isn't correct.

Comment: Try using:

<?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>